# Why does cout print char arrays differently from other arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm using C++ to understand how exactly pointers work. I have this piece of code using arrays, which I'm using just to understand how the equivalent works with pointers.

```
int main() {    
    int arr[10] = {1,2,3};    
    char arr2[10] = {'c','i','a','o','\0'};
    cout << arr << endl;
    cout << arr2 << endl;
}
```

However when I run this, `arr` outputs the address of the first element of the array of ints (as expected) but `arr2` doesn't output the address of the first element of the array of chars; it actually prints "ciao".

What is it that I'm missing or that I haven't learned yet about this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's the operator<< that is overloaded for `const void*` and for `const char*`. Your char array is converted to `const char*` and passed to that overload, because it fits better than to `const void*`. The int array, however, is converted to `const void*` and passed to that version. The version of operator<< taking `const void*` just outputs the address. The version taking the `const char*` actually treats it like a C-string and outputs every character until the terminating null character. If you don't want that, convert your char array to `const void*` explicitly when passing it to operator<<:

```
cout << static_cast<const void*>(arr2) << endl;
```

Comment: According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) it is only overloaded for void*. Does that mean it is able to determine if the pointer points to chars, and if so it looks for the terminal character and prints the string? (still a little stumped)

Comment: @rmp251: Missed [these](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/)?

Answer (score 5):

Because cout's `operator <<` is overloaded for `char*` to output strings, and `arr2` matches that.

If you want the address, try casting the character array as a void pointer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard overload for char* that outputs a NUL terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

While casting is probably a more meaningful approach, you could also use the addressof operator:

```
cout << &arr2 << endl;
```

Comment: Probably want `&arr2[0]` instead of `&arr2` here

Comment: Those are the same addresses, Shawley.

Comment: An array in C/C++ is just a series of memory locations. So the address of array is the address of the first element. Wonder why this was voted down

Comment: Mostly because it doesn't explain the idea - a char[10]* does not convert to char*.