# How does cout work when given an array?

Tags: c++, cout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does cout print char arrays differently from other arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501816/why-does-cout-print-char-arrays-differently-from-other-arrays)

If I have this code:

```
char myArray[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
cout << myArray;
```

It gives me this output:

`abc`

However, if I have this code:

```
int myArray[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
cout << myArray;
```

It gives me this output:

`0x28ff30`

Why does it not print out 123?

Comment: Why is this tagged `c`? There is no `cout` in C! And the `<<` syntax is just plain wrong! `c` tag removed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason that the first piece of code works is that the compiler is implicitly converting the array into a `const char *` character pointer, which it's then interpreting as a C-style string.  Interestingly, this code is **not** safe because your array of characters is not explicitly null-terminated.  Printing it will thus start reading and printing characters until you coincidentally find a null byte, which results in undefined behavior.

In the second case, the compiler is taking the `int` array and implicitly converting it into an `int *` pointer to the first element, then from there to a `const void *` pointer to the first element.  Printing a `const void *` pointer with `cout` just prints its address, hence the output you're getting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tch, I really must type faster! +1 for stating exactly what I wanted to say. :)

Comment: @GMan- Thanks for pointing that out!  I'll update the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

There is an `operator <<` that knows about `basic_ostream` instances (such as `cout`) on the left-hand-side and `const char*`s on the right.

There is no such operator defined for `const int*` (or `const int[]`). Although you are perfectly at liberty to create one.

Just be sure to specify a sentinel at the end of your arrays to prevent running off the end of your buffer.

The reason you see the pointer value is because there is an `basic_ostream::operator<<(const void*)` which will print this.

Answer (score 2):

std::cout is an instance of std::ostream, and there are several overloaded operators provided.

For example:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, char*);
```

When you type std::cout << somevar; compiler looks up best matching overload. First for exact type of the variable, then for anything it can be implicitly converted to (not to mention member functions/free functions/template functions, etc).

Here is a random article on [C++ Overload Resolution](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/268)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `myArray` in the context `cout << myArray;`, it decays to a pointer. The `operator<<` which takes a `char*` as its second argument outputs a string; the one which takes other types of pointer just outputs an address. Hence the observed behaviour.

Your char array is actually not null-terminated, so I guess what you're seeing in the first case is really just undefined behaviour which happens to do 'the right thing' in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed it an array of ints; you've passed it a pointer to an int. When faced with a pointer, it prints out the address that it points to. It has no way of printing out an array because it doesn't know how many elements it has (if any).

The reason it worked when you used a pointer to a character is that it knows that all arrays of characters are terminated by a NUL (`\0`) character, so it doesn't matter that you haven't told it the number of characters in your array. Keep in mind that your array is not terminated by a NUL, so it's only by luck that you got `abc` and no extra garbage characters on the end.

Comment: Why doesn't it print out the address for the first one as well then?

Comment: @John: I updated my answer with the reason.

Comment: No, he passes it an array. Of course, no overloads exist, so it looks for overloads with consideration to conversions, but it's not true he's passing it a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Because it has no way of knowing that your array is an array, or what kind of data is in it.  When you do `cout << myArray`, 'myArray' is treated as a pointer type, which may point to anything.  So instead of trying to dereference the pointer (and potentially crashing the app if the pointer has not been initialized), the address that the pointer is pointing to gets printed.

Comment: `myArray` is not treated as a pointer, it's an array. Upon finding no suitable overloads of `operator<<`, it looks for other ones available with conversions. (One being `const char*`, the other being `const void*`.)