# Why is a char pointer dereferenced automatically in a dynamic array

Tags: c++, c-strings

Perhaps a stupid question. When I `cout` the pointer to the char array, I thought it would print an address; instead it dereferences the address and prints the actual values till null.

As opposed to an int array where it does what I expect it to. It prints the address of the first element.

Why does the char element gets dereferenced when you print the pointer.

```
char* as = new char[100];
    as[0] = 'a';
    as[1] = 'b';
    as[2] = NULL;
    cout << as << endl;

    int* s = new int[100];
    s[0] = 2;
    cout << s << endl;
```

Asking this because when I try to get the address to the first char element `a[0] = 'a';`. I have to store it in a pointer to a pointer. Which seems weird to me but that's besides the point.

```
char ** d = &as;
    cout << d << "this is d" << endl;
```

Comment: char arrays = C-style strings. The system is assuming (incorrectly in this one case) that you want print out the string itself, not the string's address.

Comment: @MarcB: Argh answers in comments -.-

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Oh sorry, I thought the question was why does `cout << d` print a string... and I was wondering how that was happening.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501816/why-does-cout-print-char-arrays-differently-from-other-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no overloaded output operator `<<` that prints the address for any `char` pointer, it treats all  `char` pointers as strings. If you want to print the address of a pointer, you need to cast it to `void*`

```
std::cout << "Address of string is " << static_cast<void*>(as) << '\n';
```

---

On a side-note, the code

```
char ** d = &as;
cout << d << "this is d" << endl;
```

will ***not*** print the address of the string, i.e. the pointer contained inside `as`, instead it will print where the *variable* `as` is stored in memory. Not quite the same thing.

Comment: so, if i wanted to save the address of the first element. i would still use char * as; but if i was to print it. i'd have to type cast it? just for clarification

Comment: @tropicalmemes `as` is *itself* a pointer to the first location of the memory you allocated. And if you want to print the address `as` is pointing to then you have to cast it.

Comment: @tropicalmemes: Yes.

Answer (score 2):

`char*` character pointers are considered to be C-style null terminated strings by the `std::ostream` `<<` operator. You are right that this is a different behavior from other pointer types.

`&a` is not a pointer to `a[0]` . It is a pointer to `a` which is itself a pointer. `a` is in fact the pointer to `a[0]` and is equivalent to `&a[0]`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: By the standard library's IOStreams "module".

Answer (score 1):

It prints the string because that's what the definition of that particular `operator<<` overload *does*. Cast to `void *` if you want to print an address:

```
cout << static_cast<void *>(as) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

IOStreams treat `char*` (and `const char*`) specially, so that you can print C-strings without further effort:

```
std::cout << "hello world\n";
```

(Bear in mind that the string literal expression decays immediately to a `const char*` when passed to `operator<<`.)

If you do not want this behaviour, you can cast to `void*`:

```
char* as = new char[100];
as[0] = 'a';
as[1] = 'b';
as[2] = NULL;
cout << (void*)as << endl;
```

Your "fix" is actually broken, because you are printing the address of the pointer `as`, not the address of the array elements that `as` points to. This is indicated by the `char**` type, which you already noticed.

Answer (score 0):

The << operator is overloaded to take a `char*` and output its contents where as there is no such overload for a `int*`/`int[]`.

Comment: Nope, outputting `&as` is broken. See my answer.